# Can you put locale files into a gem?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am trying to use the same locale file in multiple apps. Can they be contained in a gem?

Comment: I'd rather use a gem, easier to have authentication with heroku

Comment: Git submodules are part of your git repo, they are just shared across multiple projects

Comment: heroku won't be able to pull down the repo if it is private

Comment: Same for a gem. Submodules arr included in your app's repo, and they are shared.

Answer (score 0):

This is definitely doable, I used https://github.com/svenfuchs/rails-i18n as a baseline